# Is teaching or teaches, is working or works

Tags: present-tense

Should I use "is teaching me" or "teaches me" in the first example and "isn't working" or "doesn't work" in the second example?
Both actions are going around the moment of speaking, but I am confused by "at the moment" in the second sentence and the fact that her father teaches her, I think can be expressed in the present simple.

1. A: "Can you drive?"
   B: "I am learning. My father teaches/is teaching me."
2. "What does your father do? He is a teacher, but he doesn't work at the moment."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Present continuous (is teaching/isn't working) is the best choice in both sentences, because both describe an ongoing situation. Simple present is also acceptable in the first sentence, but not (in my opinion) in the second. This may be because the expression "doesn't work" has an additional meaning which suggests that something has malfunctioned: this would not be appropriate in relation to your father's employment.

Comment: I thought the present simple doesn't work in the second example because of "at the moment".

Comment: @AntoniaA "at the moment" simply reinforces the now-ness of it, so that doesn't affect the ability to use present simple, though present continuous would be better in this case. For example, it is perfectly OK to say "I am busy at the moment".